# Use ODataQueryOptions in domain driven design with repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, domain-driven-design, abp

### Introduction

Good day everyone. We have a project using ABP for Domain Driven Design. We're using OData in this to allow querying our API with filters, sorting etc.

**CURRENTLY** we have a repository that accepts `ODataQueryOptions` as parameter. Since this repo is used by an application service, which is used by the controller, we're chaining these parameters and passing them through to multiple projects. Even the ones which shouldn't have any reference to the Entities.

### Context

So according to Domain Driven Design, we have multiple projects in our Solution

- Application.Contracts

  - Contains the interfaces for our application services.
  - Has reference to Domain.Shared
- Application

  - Contains the implementation of the application services
  - Has reference to Domain and Application.Shared
- Domain.Shared

  - Contains enums for example
  - All projects depend on this
- Domain

  - Contains the entities
  - Depends on Domain.Shared
- WebHost

  - Contains the controllers
  - Depends on `Application.Contracts`

Here's the image I'm using as a reference

[image: ddd projects]

So this leads to the following problem that the WebHost should not have references to an Entity. Right now, we're using `ODataQueryOptions<PersonEntity>` in our controllers, so we have dependency on the wrong projects

#### Solutions

##### EnableQuery

So the solution **COULD** be to use the `[EnableQuery]` attribute from OData, which I Did. I now have the following code

```
[HttpGet("odata/persons")]
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Person> Get([FromODataUri] string status)
{

    var persons = _personRepository.GetAll();
    return persons.AsQueryable();
}
```

The problem, however, with this is that the repository first queries everything and only THEN applies the filtering. Isn't this a performance problem? I mean, imagine we have 10000 records, then this would query 10000 records and then apply the filtering. Seems like this is a bad idea?

##### Transforming ODataQueryOptions to Linq Query

We could also transform the ODataQueryOptions to a Linq Query, but to do that, we would need to start with

```
var personsQuery = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Domain.Entities.Person>()
personsQuery = opts.Filter?.ApplyTo(personsQuery , _oDataQuerySettings) as IQueryable<Domain.Entities.Person>;
```

but this would require a reference to `_container` which is in the Infrastructure project. I'm kinda stuck on this

#### Desired solution

So, my desired solution would be, that I can make a request to my API

`GET https://myapi.com/persons?&top=1`

And I don't have a reference to ODataQueryOptions directly, but can use this filtering totally AGNOSTIC to any implementation detail in my application services and repositories without breaking DDD.

How do I combine this?

Comment: What's `_personRepository.GetAll()`? Are you using ASP.NET Boilerplate (aspnetboilerplate.com) or ABP Framework (abp.io)?

Comment: Have you had any breakthroughs here? I'm considering trying to use OData on project where repositories return aggregates